# How to hg unshelve without merge

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch, merge-conflict-resolution

Is there a way I can force `hg unshelve` without causing any merge conflicts?  Just overwrite the old files with the shelved state?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
hg unshelve --tool :other
```

Using the internal merge tool `:other` will instruct Mercurial to always prefer the shelved version to local changes. See `hg help mergetools` for more information on the various internal merge tools.